# Segmentation Fault, previously not there when compiled with GNU, Now using Clang

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, clang

So I was reading that clang is a lot more strict standards implimentation, but this one really baffles me...

```
void readInputFile(const string inputFileName, Geometry &planeGeom, FlightConditions &FC, AircraftChar & aeroChar,
vector<string> &runFileResults, int &vorlaxRun, int &lateralTrue)
{
   int inputRuns;
   char infile[32], blank, cTest[32], iTest[32];
   char aircraftInpFile[80];
   char vorlaxCommand[80];
   string casTest, inpTest;
   double S_ref,span,Cbar,Xbar,Zbar,St_ref,mac_t,Sf_ref,CD_0,Mach,Uinf,rho;
   FILE *ofpInput;

   strcpy(infile,inputFileName.c_str());
   ofpInput = fopen(infile, "r");
   assert(ofpInput!=NULL);

   fscanf(ofpInput, "%i", &lateralTrue);  //0--false only longitudinal analysis, 1--true long and lateral
   printf("lateralTrue = %i\n",lateralTrue);

   fscanf(ofpInput, "%i", &vorlaxRun);    //0--false will input aero data, 1--true will input run files and execute vorlax
   printf("Are we running Vorlax? -- %i\n",vorlaxRun);

   fscanf(ofpInput, "%i", &inputRuns);             //for looping to run all the needed vorlax files
   printf("inputRuns = %i\n",inputRuns);
   runFileResults.resize(2*inputRuns);

   cout << "I made it to the part where I am reading" << vorlaxRun << "\n" << endl;

   fscanf(ofpInput, "%s", &blank);    //reading in data from input file
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.S, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.b, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.cBar, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.xBar, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.zBar, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.St, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.mact, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &planeGeom.Sf, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &aeroChar.CD_0, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &aeroChar.e, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &FC.mach, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &FC.uinf, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &FC.rho, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &FC.alpha, &blank);
   fscanf(ofpInput, "%lf %s", &aeroChar.dEdA, &blank);

   cout << "I made it past reading all the planeGeom stuff " << vorlaxRun << "\n" << endl;

   //Commented out code section for debugging purposes...

   cout << "I made it past reading all the aeroChar stuff" << "\n" << endl;
```

So it seemed that the int vorlaxRun was causing the issues oddly enough so I added it to my prints (as you see above) to see what's going on and this is the output I get.

```
Reading inputFileMavericAftCGApproachFlapsDown.dat
lateralTrue = 0
Are we running Vorlax? -- 0
inputRuns = 0
I made it to the part where I am reading0

Segmentation fault: 11
```

If I take out the second instance of vorlaxRun being printed this is what I get

```
Reading inputFileMavericAftCGApproachFlapsDown.dat
lateralTrue = 0
Are we running Vorlax? -- 0
inputRuns = 0
I made it to the part where I am reading0

I made it past reading all the planeGeom stuff 

I made it past reading all the aeroChar stuff

Abort trap: 6
```

I think I would expect the abort trap 6 since I had to comment out a bunch of lines in the process of seeing what was happening.  But I don't understand why removing the second instance of printing the variable to the screen caused it to magically work... or why if I add it on the very last cout then I get this:

```
 Reading inputFileMavericAftCGApproachFlapsDown.dat
 lateralTrue = 0
 Are we running Vorlax? -- 0
 inputRuns = 0
 I made it to the part where I am reading0

 I made it past reading all the planeGeom stuff 

 Segmentation fault: 11
```

Hopefully I have provided enough information.  I am completely new to clang and I never had any issues with this in g++ after googling and searching I'm still lost...

Comment: Why are you mixing C code with C++?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` or `clang -Wall -g`). I did not read your code, but I guess you have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Use the `gdb` debugger

Comment: `fscanf(ofpInput, "%s", &blank);` is  very probably [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Read the documentation of every function you are calling, notably http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: Also stick with either C or C++ code - especially when IO is involved. The two mechanisms do not work that well together IMHO.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes it was indeed the blank variable that was giving me issues.  Oddly enough I got away with the behavior in g++...probably dumb luck.  The weird thing is that the debugging information was not pointing to it?  Oh well figured this out days ago, sometimes writing out a stackoverflow question serves the same function as having a duck

Comment: @Ed Heal, If I recall correctly (this was written quite awhile ago) I couldn't figure out how to use the c++ basic cout to read from the file without having to bookkeep what line number I was on and fscanf alleviated this issue I think.  If there is a better way to read in from a file without having to keep track of wether or not I'm at the end of the line or telling it to advance to the next line that would be great to know, perhaps you can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

As Basile Starynkevitch correctly pointed out, your program exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A program exhibiting such behavior could do *anything*. That includes *appearing* to work correctly when compiled with one compiler, while crashing when compiled with another (or with different optimization level, or for a different platform).

Such a program could also appear to behave erratically, such as crashing in random places, or crashing differently when some parts of it are commented out.

The *first* (but by no means the only) instance of undefined behavior can be guessed from this code snippet:

```
char infile[32], ...;
strcpy(infile,inputFileName.c_str());
```

We can guess from your output that `inputFileName` has a value `"inputFileMavericAftCGApproachFlapsDown.dat"`, which requires 42 characters to store in an array, and you are copying that value into a 32-byte buffer, thus causing a stack overflow (which is one of many ways to produce undefined behavior).

By the way, that copy is completely pointless and serves no useful purpose. And you should pass `inputFileName` by const reference instead of by value.

So, what should you do?

1. Find a capable mentor who knows something about `C` and `C++`, you *really* need one.
2. Read documentation as Basile suggested.
3. Compile your code with [Address Sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) (supported by both Clang and GCC). If will find this particular bug, as well as the one Basile pointed out in comments, and possibly many more.
4. Once you fixed all of the bugs Address Sanitizer finds, proceed to [Memory Sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) for more bugs.

After your program is sanitizer-clean, it will have a better chance of working correctly, though still by no means guaranteed to be bug-free.

Comment: Well thanks for pointing out that I "really need" a c++ mentor.  This is old code from several years ago I'm trying to revive with minimal effort, comments like that are snarky and unnecessary in a learning environment.  Yes I compiled it with address sanitizer and that didnt help hence why I posted here, in fact the debugging info I got pointed me to the variable vorlaxRun.